# css preceded element and :focus

Tags: html, css, focus

I have to change background color after click on input and preceded `<p>` element. It's not difficult with only `input`, but `<p>` it is.

**Code**

```css
    input[type="text"]:focus ~ .prefix{
       background-color:#e4ff00 !important;
    }

    input[type="text"]:focus + .prefix{
       background-color:#e4ff00 !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="inputholder holder50">
       <p class="prefix">NIP</p>
       <input type="text" value="" name="nip">
    </div>
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use p in donwards it will work

```html
<div class="inputholder holder50">
   <input type="text" value="" name="nip">   
   <p class="prefix">NIP</p>
</div>

<style>
input[type="text"]:focus ~ .prefix{
background-color:#e4ff00 !important;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + .prefix{
background-color:#e4ff00 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're asking is technically impossible: it is not possible – with the current selectors module – to select a previous element. Both the adjacent-sibling and general-sibling combinators (`+` and `~` respectively) can only select elements that follow the current element.

Similarly, there is no parent-selector.

That said, though, this is possible if you can rearrange your HTML to place the `<p>` element *after* the `<input>` element:

```css
  input[type="text"]:focus + .prefix {
    background-color: #e4ff00;
  }
```

```html
<div class="inputholder holder50">
  <input type="text" value="" name="nip">
  <p class="prefix">NIP</p>
</div>
```

If, however, you need the `<p>` element to precede the `<input>` that is also possible, albeit it's effectively a visual trick using CSS flex-boxes to reorder the visual flow of the page while the `<p>` element remains a later-sibling of the `<input>` in the HTML:

```css
.inputholder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

div.inputholder p.prefix {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: auto;
}

div.inputholder input {
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}


input:focus + p {
  background-color: #e4ff00;;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputholder holder50">
  <input type="text" value="" name="nip">
  <p class="prefix">NIP</p>
</div>
```

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).
- "[Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)," (MDN).